How to write xpath to fetch value for a label
Need to get XPath should use label to fetch the respective value.

The XPath that you are looking for is
//div[@class='PZeSbe'][.//a[text()='Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)']]//span[contains(@class,'Ykn2A')]

You can use it like
String url = "https://pagespeed.web.dev/";
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

String testUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
driver.findElement(By.id("i4")).sendKeys(testUrl + "\n");

String[] labels = {"Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)", "Interaction to Next Paint (INP)", "Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)", "First Contentful Paint (FCP)", "First Input Delay (FID)", "Time to First Byte (TTFB)"};

for (String label : labels) {
    String value = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='PZeSbe'][.//a[text()='"+ label +"']]//span[contains(@class,'Ykn2A')]"))).getText();
    System.out.println(label + ": " + value);
}

driver.quit();

which prints
Largest Contentful Paint (LCP): 1.2 s
Interaction to Next Paint (INP): 250 ms
Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS): 0.04
First Contentful Paint (FCP): 1 s
First Input Delay (FID): 28 ms
Time to First Byte (TTFB): 0.5 s


How to get values for Mobile and desktop? Currently from your suggestion, could see only one output is printed.

You asked for an XPath that works on both.... I gave you that so this question is answered. I went on to fix the entire script to output the data for the Mobile tab as an example.

Kudos JeffC.  You made my day. It works. Unable to upvote as reputation is 0.

You can accept the answer with no/low reputation.
